# Offline webreader for iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, software-recommendation

Do you know of a good app for iPod touch that let's me quickly take a bunch of webpages offline that contain some articles I want to read later when I don't have an internet connection? It would be cool if it could also strip out the noise like ads, navigation, header, footer and leave nothing but the actual article. Also when reading later it should give me as much real estate as possible for the actual content having absolutely no chrome visible just like the kindle app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/iphone)
(I don't feel the need to write the features list as you did it already in your question :)

Comment: Instapaper is great, but it seems that it doesn't have a fullscreen mode, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using Instapaper, as I like their features better.
However a friend of mine enjoys [read it later](http://readitlaterlist.com/)

Answer (score -2):

or just take a screen shot...(home button+snooz button)

Comment: That's not what the user is looking fr